# find interior points, boundary points and closure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For the following cases, determine the interior points, boundary points and closure

S<sub>1</sub> =  {1} ∪ [2, 3] ∪ (4, 5) ⊆ R

Here's what I have so far:

int(S<sub>1</sub>) = all points in (4,5) ∪ (2,3)

bd(S<sub>1</sub>) = {1,2,3}

cl(S<sub>1</sub>) = int(S) ∪ bd(S) = {1,2,3} ∪ (4,5) ∪ (2,3)

Does that seem right? Is there some way we can define the closure to be more concise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boundary is $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and closure is $\{1\} \cup [2,3] \cup [4,5]$.

Comment: Why do we include [4,5] in the boundary if they form an open set?

Comment: $[4,5]$ is not an open set. Boundary of  a set is closure minus the interior. So take the closure of $(4,5)$ and then remove $(4,5)$.

Comment: I meant (4,5) belongs to S1, so 4 and 5 are not included in the given set. Are they allowed to form the boundary?

Comment: Boundary points of a set need not be points of the set.